# Vue 3: Vue.createApp is not a constructor

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

I am brand new to Vue and am trying to learn how to use it.

I think I am getting tripped up trying to mount a new Vue app.

Here is what I can get to work:

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>
<script>
const vm = new Vue({})
</script>
```

from there I am able to mount it and use everything correctly.

However, this currently loads an older version of Vue (2.6.7)

I'd like to learn on the newest version (Vue 3) so I tried importing the package [recommended by Vue docs](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/installation.html#cdn):

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@next"></script>
<script>
const vm = new Vue({})
</script>
```

and I get the following error in console:

> Uncaught TypeError: Vue is not a constructor

I also tried mimicking the syntax from [Vue 3's docs](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/component-registration.html#component-names).

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@next"></script>
<script>
const vm = new Vue.createApp({})
</script>
```

but it throws the same error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Vue.createApp is not a constructor

Using a different CDN or a specific version (vue@3.0.2) also gives me the same result.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

[`createApp`](https://v3.vuejs.org/api/global-api.html#createapp) is not an object it's a function that returns an instance of vue app, so it should be :

```
 const vm = Vue.createApp({}) //remove the new
```

> **createApp**
> Returns an application instance which provides an application context. The entire component tree mounted by the application instance share the same context
> `const app = Vue.createApp({})`